# It doesn't insert the data into a table using UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

when I insert the results of a query using union, it only insert the results of the first query. Whilst the second query after the UNION is not inserted nor included. How do I insert both results of two separate queries combined using UNION

```
INSERT INTO ResourceTaskFact.dbo.Region
SELECT 'Region1' AS RegionView,
       'R1'      AS RegionViewCode,
       sl.sublocationstring,
       sl.subLocationCode,
       l.locationcode,
       r.regioncode,
       rg.RegionGrpCode,
       d.DivisionCode,
       dg.DivisionGrpCode,
       --
       sl.SubLocationDescription,
       l.LocationDescription,
       r.regiondescription,
       rg.RegionGrpDescription,
       d.divisionDescription,
       dg.DivisionGrpDescription
FROM   SMECSubLocation sl,
       Location l,
       Region r,
       RegionGrp rg,
       Division d,
       DivisionGrp dg
WHERE  l.LocationCode = sl.LocationCode
       AND r.RegionCode = l.RegionCode
       AND r.RegionGrpCode = rg.RegionGrpCode
       AND d.divisioncode = rg.divisioncode
       AND d.divisiongrpcode = dg.divisiongrpcode
UNION
SELECT 'Region2',
       'R2',
       sl.sublocationstring,
       sl.subLocationCode,
       l.locationcode,
       r.regioncode,
       rg.RegionGrpCode,
       d.DivisionCode,
       dg.DivisionGrpCode,
       --
       sl.SubLocationDescription,
       l.LocationDescription,
       r.regiondescription,
       rg.RegionGrpDescription,
       d.divisionDescription,
       dg.DivisionGrpDescription
FROM   SMECVirtualSubLocation sl,
       SCVirtualLocation l,
       SCVirtualRegion r,
       SCVirtualRegionGrp rg,
       SCVirtualDivision d,
       SCVirtualDivisionGrp dg
WHERE  l.LocationCode = sl.LocationCode
       AND r.RegionCode = l.RegionCode
       AND r.RegionGrpCode = rg.RegionGrpCode
       AND d.divisioncode = rg.divisioncode
       AND d.divisiongrpcode = dg.divisiongrpcode
       AND sl.CustomOrgCode = 'DEF'
       AND l.CustomOrgCode = 'DEF'
       AND r.CustomOrgCode = 'DEF'
       AND rg.CustomOrgCode = 'DEF'
       AND d.CustomOrgCode = 'DEF'
       AND dg.CustomOrgCode = 'DEF'
```

Thanks in Advance!

Beau

Comment: Remove insert and check if Select is working ?

Comment: Random guess: The second part of the UNION returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you have the same number of columns and of same types in the two SELECTs.
- Make sure both SELECTs are returning results.
- Try using UNION ALL instead, in case both your queries are returning the same row.

*UNION removes duplicate records (where all columns in the results are the same), UNION ALL does not.*

Comment: The hardcoded `'Region2'` and `'Region1'` make it impossible for both branches to have any of the same rows.

Comment: The first query gives 162 results/rows which is correct whilst the second query also provide 162 results/rows as well, when I run both using UNION, it gives 324 results/rows.